# Super logarithmic inverse of tetration

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, inverse, tetration

**What's the super logarithmic inverse of tetration for $\bf{^{2}{x}}$?**

Is it $slog^{x}_{2}$?

Comment: I presume you've already looked into previous work by Ioannis Galidakis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse function of ${^x{2}}$ is the base-2 super-log of x, which is what you wrote. The inverse function of ${^2{x}}$ is the 2nd super-root of x.

While the super-log seems to have a more commonly accepted notation (slog), there is no such notation for super-root (or, if you wish, dozens of notations). There are also some places (like Wikipedia's Tetration page) that call the 2nd super-root the "super-sqrt" function. But that's OK, because lots of things in mathematics don't have unique notations. Take $e$ for example. It is used for basis vectors, physical constants, dimensional units, other variables, and the "base of the natural logarithm".

So if you're looking for terminology, the inverse of  ${^2{x}}$ is called "super-root", but if you're looking for notation, just use $f(x)$, along with the explanation: "where $f$ is the second super-root".

Comment: Thanks [Andrew](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/25049/andrew-robbins), I think that helped solve my problem. One question though: you mentioned that the inverse of $\bf{^2}{x}$ to be the 2$^{nd}$ super-root of $x$. Would my $\bf{slog^x_2}$ still satisfy?

Comment: No, super-roots and super-logs are different functions, they do not satisfy each other's equations.

Comment: Apologies, it's 4AM here. Only after rereading your answer did I realise you were talking about super roots on the same paragraph that you discussed super logarithms.

Comment: **+1** and accepted. Thanks for your help